# Use rsync to backup .ecryptfs, but also use exclude some folders inside

Tags: backup, encryption, rsync, ecryptfs

I want to backup the `/home/.ecryptfs` folder on my machine using `rsync`. I don't want to back up the unencrypted files. However, I want to exclude certain folders. For example, music, downloads, or virtual machines.

I have figured out that if I run the command a few times, and look through things carefully I can find the corresponding `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.XXXX-XXX--` folder. However, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the eCryptfs tools? Specifically

> `ecryptfs-find` - use inode numbers to match encrypted/decrypted filenames
>
> SYNOPSIS
>   `ecryptfs-find   cleartext-filename`  `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.fwBGx18a.UcYl18CF7VKLMSDuEadV`
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          This program will attempt to match encrypted filenames to their decrypted counterpart,  and
>          attempt to match decrypted filenames to their encrypted counterpart.
>
> Notes:
>        - the eCryptfs filesystem must be mounted in order to work
>        - it uses ls(1) in order to determine the inode
>        - it uses find(1) in order to locate the inode

And, you could always move some of the (larger) folders (that contain no sensitive data) out of your encrypted home, music might be a good candidate to be unencrypted.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `--exclude` using the file to exclude in their encrypted form

```
rsync --exclude=`ecryptfs-map folder-to-exclude` source target
```

ecryptfs-map can be found at https://gist.github.com/monperrus/7a114ccc1c2fd20dcc5e852cdf813c5d